# "Гложет"

Tags: грамотная-речь

На одном сообществе попался интересный вопрос. Есть такое слово "гложет". Но как это слово склоняется по временам? Как будет в будущем или прошедшем времени? "Глодал"? Но тогда в настоящем должно быть "глодает".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос интересный. С.И. Ожегов дает формы "гложу, гложешь" в переносном значение (терзать, мучить).Естественнно, в прошедшем времени будет форма "гложила тоска", "гложили сомнения", а вот будущее время образуется с помощью глагола "будет" (будет гложить тоска). Но у того же Ожегова нет инфинитива "гложить", а есть лишь "глодать". Но мы ведь не напишем "меня будет глодать тоска", "будут глодать сомнения"? Скорее прозвучит "будут гложить сомнения", "будет гложить тоска". Правда, здесь возникает вопрос об окончании "-ешь", "-ет", ведь "гложить" - глагол 2 спряжения на -ить.В общем, путаница какая-то.
    Что касается прямого смысла (глодать кость), то, мне думается, это слово употребляется как в приставочной, так и в бесприставочной форме: глодает, обглодает кость

Comment: Вы что-то очень смело формы констуируете.
"Гложил", "гложить" нету ни в одном словаре.  
Касательно будущего времени - совсем уж непонятно. Я бы написал "будут глодать" - и не зщадумался.

Answer (score 0):

Да, будет "глодал". Правда это крайне сомнительный вариант в плане употребимости. Но вот "его глодали сомнения", думаю, вполне возможно.

Что касается утверждения *в настоящем должно быть "глодает"*, то оно, разумеется, неверно. Такой однозначности нет вообще, по формы прошедшего времени обычно образованы по фонетическим законам, отличным от современных.

Гложет обычно не используется в первом-втором лице, но в принципе в настоящем времени возможно (как разговорный вариант) "Я глодаю" и т.д. Так что ничего удивительного в том, что вы восстановили форму настоящего времени как "глодает".

UPD

Нормативный вариант: - *я глож**у**, ты гложешь и т.д.*